# UIColor initializer (cannot find an initializer of type 'UIColor' that accepts ....) error

Tags: swift, uipickerview, uicolor

I know it is not an appropriate way to do this but for the purpose of learning I have a picker control with four components and 255 rows in each to change the 'view' background color based on RGB-alpha.
I know `UIColor(red: <#CGFloat#>, green: <#CGFloat#>, blue: <#CGFloat#>, alpha: <#CGFloat#>)` accepts four float numbers as parameter for each color but I get the error:
Cannot find an initializer for type 'UIColor' that accepts an argument list of type '(red: Float, green: Float, blue: Float, alpha: Float)'
What is wrong?

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    var newbackgroundColor = UIColor()

    var redCode: Float = 0.0
    var greenCode: Float = 0.0
    var blueCode: Float = 0.0
    var alphaCode: Float = 0.0

    if component == 0 {
        switch row {
        case 0..<256:
            redCode = Float(row/255)
            newbackgroundColor = UIColor(red: redCode, green: greenCode, blue: blueCode, alpha: alphaCode)
        default:
            break
        }

    } else if component == 1 {
        switch row {
        case 0..<256:
            greenCode = Float(row/255)
            newbackgroundColor = UIColor(red: redCode, green: greenCode, blue: blueCode, alpha: alphaCode)
        default:
            break
        }

    } else if component == 2{
        switch row {
        case 0..<256:
            blueCode = Float(row/255)
            newbackgroundColor = UIColor(red: redCode, green: greenCode, blue: blueCode, alpha: alphaCode)
        default:
            break
        }

    } else {
        switch row {
        case 0..<256:
            alphaCode = Float(row/255)
            newbackgroundColor = UIColor(red: redCode, green: greenCode, blue: blueCode, alpha: alphaCode)
        default:
            break
        }

    }

    self.view.backgroundColor = newbackgroundColor
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CGFloat` not `Float`

Check the API docs when you get an error like this

Comment: I didn't know that CGFloat is also a type!! :D

Comment: Most of the CG and NS types made it across to Swift as they are needed for all the Framework API

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that Float is not the same as CGFloat, you can make it much easier like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 4
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 256
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0))/255, green: CGFloat(pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1))/255, blue: CGFloat(pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(2))/255, alpha: CGFloat(pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(3))/255)
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
        return "\(row)"
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        pickerView.selectRow(255, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: false)
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 2, animated: false)
        pickerView.selectRow(255, inComponent: 3, animated: false)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0))/255, green: CGFloat(pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1))/255, blue: CGFloat(pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(2))/255, alpha: CGFloat(pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(3))/255)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8yzdavecbjjnol/uiPickerView.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks buddy! It really helped because I am new to iOS development.